# How to change the background color of a SceneView 3D Object in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, scenekit

Does anybody knows how to change the color of the background of a SceneView object?
I'm trying by just placing the background attribute to the SceneView, but it doesn't change it, still with a default background.[In this case I wanted to the background be green, but it's keeps gray/white](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hb18o.png)

```
import SwiftUI
import SceneKit

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
    
        ZStack{
            Color.red
            SceneView(
                scene: SCNScene(named: "Earth.scn"),
                options: [.autoenablesDefaultLighting,.allowsCameraControl]
            )
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height/2, alignment: .center)
            .background(Color.green)
            .border(Color.blue, width: 3)
        
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: you could try ".colorMultiply(Color.green)" instead of ".background(Color.green)" but I'm not sure of the side effects.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The gray that you are seeing is from `SCNScene`'s [`background`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscene/1523665-background) property. You need to set this to `UIColor.green`.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack{
            Color.red
            SceneView(
                scene: {
                    let scene = SCNScene(named: "Earth.scn")!
                    scene.background.contents = UIColor.green /// here!
                    return scene
                }(),
                options: [.autoenablesDefaultLighting, .allowsCameraControl]
            )
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height/2, alignment: .center)
            .border(Color.blue, width: 3)
            
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: green background in SceneView]

Comment: How can I make it transparent? I tried UIColor.clear but it makes it white instead.

Comment: @SuscaBogdan `SceneView` in SwiftUI doesn't support this yet, but this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67557700/14351818

Comment: It seems that it doesn't differentiate colors from xcassets i.e. dark light and you need to set correct UIColor directly both for dark and light mode :(